# Inconsistent evaluation for `constexpr` lambdas in templates between `static_assert`, `if constexpr(...)` and `constexpr` variables

Tags: c++, lambda, constexpr, c++17, constant-expression

*(Using `g++ 7.0` trunk.)*

Given the following "type-to-value wrapping" utilities...

```
template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper { using type = T; };

// "Wraps" a type into a `constexpr` value.
template <typename T>
constexpr type_wrapper<T> type_c{};
```

...I created the following function that checks the validity of an expression:

```
template <typename TF>
constexpr auto is_valid(TF)
{
    return [](auto... ts) constexpr 
    {
        return std::is_callable<TF(typename decltype(ts)::type...)>{};
    };
}
```

---

The `is_valid` function can be used as follows:

```
// Evaluates to `true` if `some_A.hello()` is a valid expression.
constexpr auto can_add_int_and_float = 
    is_valid([](auto _0) constexpr -> decltype(_0.hello()){})
        (type_c<A>);

// Evaluates to `true` if `some_int + some_float` is a valid expression.
constexpr auto can_add_int_and_float = 
    is_valid([](auto _0, auto _1) constexpr -> decltype(_0 + _1){})
        (type_c<int>, type_c<float>);
```

It can also be used inside `static_assert`...

```
static_assert(is_valid([](auto _0) constexpr -> decltype(_0.hello()){})
        (type_c<A>));
```

...and inside `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr(
     is_valid([](auto _0) constexpr -> decltype(_0.hello()){})
        (type_c<A>)) { /* ... */ }
```

---

However, when `is_valid` is used inside a template function *(passing the template parameters as `type_c` values)*, something weird happens:

- `static_assert(is_valid(/*...*/))` works properly.
- `constexpr auto x = is_valid(/*...*/)` works properly.
- `if constexpr(is_valid(/*...*/)` **fails to compile**.

```
// Compiles and works as intended.
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void sum_ok_0(T0, T1)
{
    static_assert(
         is_valid([](auto _0, auto _1) constexpr 
              -> decltype(_0 + _1){})(type_c<T0>, type_c<T1>)
    ); 
}

// Compiles and works as intended.
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void sum_ok_1(T0, T1)
{
    constexpr auto can_sum =
         is_valid([](auto _0, auto _1) constexpr 
              -> decltype(_0 + _1){})(type_c<T0>, type_c<T1>); 

    if constexpr(can_sum) { }
}

// Compile-time error!
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void sum_fail_0(T0, T1)
{
    if constexpr(is_valid([](auto _0, auto _1) constexpr 
         -> decltype(_0 + _1){})(type_c<T0>, type_c<T1>)) { } 
}
```

Error:

```
In function 'void sum_fail_0(T0, T1)':
64:95: error: expression '<lambda>' is not a constant expression
     if constexpr(is_valid([](auto _0, auto _1) constexpr -> decltype(_0 + _1){})(type_c<T0>, type_c<T1>)) { }
```

**Why is this failing to compile only for the `if constexpr(is_valid(/*...*/))` case?** This is inconsistent with `static_assert` and `constexpr auto x = /*...*/`.

Is this a defect in `g++`'s implementation of `if constexpr`?

[**Full example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EDMSA5UVXqZR9kcQ).

Comment: You reinvented [std::is_callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: not anymore :)

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistent behavior was reported as [bug #78131](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78131).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, the lambda itself isn't a `constexpr`.
You can do

```
constexpr auto f = [](auto _0, auto _1) -> decltype(_0 + _1){};
```

And then

```
if constexpr(is_valid(f)(type_c<T0>, type_c<T1>)) { }
```

Comment: Even explicitly saying `is_valid([](auto _0, auto _1) constexpr -> decltype(_0 + _1){}` does not change the outcome. Why would putting the lambda itself in a `constexpr` variable and in a `static_assert` work but not in `if constexpr`?